# Pin<&mut MaybeUninit<T>> into Pin<&mut T>

Tags: rust, unsafe

How do I safely get `Pin<&mut T>` from `Pin<&mut MaybeUninit<T>>`, assuming `MaybeUninit<T>` is initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be safe via [`Pin::map_unchecked_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.map_unchecked_mut):

```
let pin_uninit_t: Pin<&mut MaybeUninit<T>> = ...;
let pin_t: Pin<&mut T> = unsafe { pin_uninit_t.map_unchecked_mut(|m| m.assume_init_mut()) };
```

The function is `unsafe` because you are given unprotected mutable access to a value you must not move, but we are not moving the value (`assume_init_mut` is a simple reference cast) so it is safe assuming the `MaybeUninit<T>` is initialized.